# Split the string into two based on a last two occurrence of a delimiter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, string

I need to split a string into two based on last two occurrence of a same delimiter.

```
Example:

"this_is_an_example".split_by_last_two_occurance("_") => #[this_is, an_example]

"this_is_an_example_string".split_by_last_two_occurance("_")  => #["this_is_an", "example_string"]
```

As far as I tried,

```
splitted_string = "this_is_an_example_string".split("_")

string_array = [splitted_string[0..-3].join("_"), splitted_string[-3,-1].join("_")]
=> #["this_is_an", "example_string"]
```

This doesn't looks like an efficient way to do it.
Is there any other way to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regular expression:

```
"this_is_an_example_string".split(/_(?=[^_]*_[^_]*$)/)
# => ["this_is_an", "example_string"]
```